# Quillen functors and stable model categories

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

Are there any books or papers where I can find some general statements and methods for working with Quillen functors that are not equivalences (and not localizations)? In particular, I would like to know which structured are preserved by Quillen functors between stable homotopy categories. I wasn't able to find much in Hovey's book.

P.S. Does there exist something like "Model categories for dummies"?:)

Comment: I was going to recommend Hovey's book! Why do you say you didn't find much there? What did you expect to find?

Comment: "model categories don't make it easy to prove that a left Quillen functor preserves finite homotopy limits, but in fact when it's between stable model categories it's automatic (this is in Hovey)." : a comment by Marc Hoyois.                            Yet I was not able to find anything like that in Hovey. So I wonder whether there exist some more sources on the subject (or possibly somebody could explain me how to read Hovey).

Comment: Derived left Quillen functors preserve homotopy push outs and finite coproducts, these coincide with homotopy pull backs and finite products by stability, hence all finite homotopy limits are preserved